# Ambiguous use of 'cornerRadius' in ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to use "Sign in with Apple" in my app and according to design better to set cornerRadius to half of heoght of the button.
I've tried to test cornerRadius in sample project from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple

So, I've tested sample project, here's my code:

```
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
private func setupProviderLoginView() {
    let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .whiteOutline)
    authorizationButton.cornerRadius = 100
    authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.signInWithAppleView.addSubview(authorizationButton)
    authorizationButton.fillSuperview()
}
```

On sample project all works fine, but on my project there is error on .cornerRaduis line:

> Ambiguous use of 'cornerRadius'

What's the problem of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
        (authorizationButton as UIControl).cornerRadius = 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
authorizationButton.cornerRadius = 100
```

with

```
authorizationButton.layer.cornerRadius = 100
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Also Apple created property cornerRadius directly for ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.

Answer (score 0):

you can quick fix this issue like below: `appleBtn.setValue(24, forKey: "cornerRadius")`.
It's ugly, I cannot find out a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
authorizationButton.setCornerRadius(radius: 25)
```

Try this, it will work.